# XQuery is not geting validate for Order by clause

Tags: xpath, xquery

```
for $i in cts:search(fn:collection()/article, $query)
    let $snippet :=  
        search:snippet( $i,.....)  

  order by if ($randomize) then ()   
     else if($sort-by = "ascending") then  
      xs:date($i/date_posted), cts:score($i)  
     else xs:date($i/date_posted) descending, cts:score($i) descending    

return
 element{"article"}
{ .....
  .....
  .....
}
```

**Problem:**
In above x-query statement, the order by clause has a condition that `if($randomize) then ()` else the output provided will be in descending manner.

I
have a requirement that according the sort-type provided by user I want to pull out the results in ascending or descending manner.

But for the above written code, my x-query statements won't validate.

Thanks in Advance,
~Prashant

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately sort specifications in XQuery are static, even more so than in XSLT. If you want to switch dynamically between an ascending or descending sort, the only way to do it is to invert the sort key. That's easy for numbers - just use -(KEY) instead of (KEY). It's not too difficult for dates either - subtract the date from some fixed date in the future (well, any date actually). I can't think of any convenient way to do it for strings, but fortunately you don't seem to be using strings.

Comment: Seems that for strings a suitable for descending sort key is: `translate(., $vAlpha, reverse($vAlpha))` where $vAlpha is the used "alphabet" in sorted order -- probably sorted by the code-points values would generally "work".